# Retrieving XML and/or JSON data from another site

Tags: c#, json, web

Good morning everyone,

I recently got a request if it's possible to retrieve data from other sites search results. I tried searching, but didn't exactly know how to word my searching.

Best explained by example.

Visit: https://bcbst.vitalschoice.com/professional?search_specialty_id=29&ci=DFT&geo_location=33688&network_id=39&sort=relevancy&radius=any&page=1

You'll see a list of doctors.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically get the list of doctors. Like the name, address, phone.

I just need some direction as I will probably be doing this for multiple sites.

I program in C# and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the website you linked it has an [API](https://bcbst.vitalschoice.com/api) available for use. What you can do is make an AJAX request (if using JQuery) or WebRequest (if using C#) to one of the endpoints, and then convert the JSON you get from the website into whatever you need to use.

You can test what you'll be getting back from the server by typing the url into the browser, [example](https://bcbst.vitalschoice.com/api/professionals/search?geo_location=Boston,+MA&radius=5.0&sort=distance+asc)

As for the search parameters, you'll have to add those to the url. I'd advise taking a look at their API to see what functions they support.

Hope this helps!

Comment: THANKS! How did you find the api info? I searched through the site looking for that.

Comment: I actually found it by going to Inspect Element (right click on the page in chrome or firefox, probably IE too) and heading over to the network tab. Refreshed the page and saw loads of calls containing /api, so I figured that would be where the API was located